# Dividing code into functions in C

Tags: c, function, memory

I am coming back to C after along time not using it. I was just practicing and came across this problem. I am trying to:

1. take 2 variables from scanf()
2. multiply the two inputs
3. then output the problem

I was trying to split the different parts up into functions but the program gives be crazy high numbers (think they are the memory addresses instead). It is probably due to my lack of misunderstanding.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int input();
int mult ( int x, int y );

int main()
{
 int x;
 int y;

 x, y = input();

 printf( "In Main: x, y: %d, %d\n", (x, y) );
 z = mult(x,y);
 printf( "The product of your two numbers is %d\n", z );

 getchar();
 getchar();
}


int input()
{
 int i_x;
 int i_y;    

 printf( "Please input two numbers to be multiplied: " );
 scanf( "%d", &i_x );
 scanf( "%d", &i_y );
 printf( "In Input: x, y: %d, %d\n", i_x, i_y );
 return i_x, i_y;
}


int mult (int x, int y)
{
 int a;
 int b;
 int c;

 a = x;
 b = y;

 printf( "In Multi: x, y: %d, %d\n", a, b );

 c = a*b;

 return c;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`x, y = input();` is not doing what you are expecting. You can't return two values from a function. You should read about [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

I would rather suggest pass the address of `x` and `y` to the function `input`. Change prototype first

```
void input(int *, int *);
```

then call it as

```
input(&x, &y);
```

and change the definition

```
void input(int *i_x, int *i_y)
{
     printf( "Please input two numbers to be multiplied: " );
     scanf( "%d", i_x );
     scanf( "%d", i_y );
     printf( "In Input: x, y: %d, %d\n", *i_x, *i_y );
}
```

Comment: thank you that is really helpful. just a little confused. so in the new code, you are effectively say   *i_x = &x;    (which i understand) however i do not understand   scanf("%d", i_x);    Surely you want to say scanf("%d", *i_x) because *i_x point to the value of x. sorry can you expand a little further please?

Answer (score 0):

`main` should return a value, as it is defined as `int`.
`return i_x, i_y;` is returning only `i_y` by the definition of the [[comma operator]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). By the same definition `x, y = input();` is only assigning `y`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @haccks, assignment of x & y through call to input() will not work properly.
Variable x will just have unitialised junk value, and will impact output accordingly.
To verify, if you initialize x to 1, the output should then be same as the second input (i_y).

Answer (score 0):

Like @haccks said, u can't return two values from a function. Rather define the the arguments for input() as pointer variables and make input() and return void.

so ur final code can look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void input(int *i_x, int *i_y);
int mult ( int x, int y );

int main()
{
int x;
int y;
int z;

input (&x, &y);

printf( "In Main: x, y: %d, %d\n", x, y);
z = mult(x,y);
printf( "The product of your two numbers is %d\n", z );

getchar();
getchar();
} 


void input(int *i_x, int *i_y)
{    

  printf( "Please input two numbers to be multiplied: " );
  scanf( "%d", i_x );
  scanf( "%d", i_y );
  printf( "In Input: x, y: %d, %d\n", *i_x, *i_y );

}

int mult (int x, int y)
{
 int a;
 int b;
 int c;

 a = x;
 b = y;

 printf( "In Multi: x, y: %d, %d\n", a, b );

 c = a*b;

 return c;
}
```

Comment: thank you that is really helpful. just a little confused. so in the new code, you are effectively say   *i_x = &x;    (which i understand) however i do not understand   scanf("%d", i_x);    Surely you want to say scanf("%d", *i_x) because *i_x point to the value of x. sorry can you expand a little further please?

Comment: Remember scanf requires u to reference the begging of the address value of the variable that is going to store the value. So automatically when a pointer is used in scanf (granted it's already pointing to the address of a value, in this case i_x = &x) the variable has already referenced the address. This eliminates the incorrect scanf(&i_x). Also a pointer itself is basically a variable referencing the beginning of an address so it can still be used in scanf without pointing to a variable but still using scanf(i_x) .